# Does downloading Ubuntu 12.04 LTS normally take around 10 hrs?

Tags: wubi, system-installation

I started downloading Ubuntu 12.04 LTS through Wubi installer and it shows nearly 10 hrs required for download. Disk space required is 18 GB which is readily available. Should it actually take that long to be downloaded?

Answer (score 2):

It completely depends on the speed of your internet connection.If you had highspeed internet connection then it would be downloaded within a hour.For slow connections it takes long time.

Comment: After running download for about 2 hrs it shows an error. "Extraction failed with code:2." What should i do?

Comment: Ask it as another question.

Answer (score 0):

It will vary depending on the capabilities of your internet connection, the capabilities of the server's internet connection, and whether you are using any of your internet bandwidth for other activities at the same time. My internet connection is rated at 1.5mbs which considered slow and is the bare minimum to qualify as highspeed internet. It takes me about 1 hour and 35-45 minutes to download 700mb of data if I can get a download speed of 150-180kbps which is usually as high as I can get unless I'm downloading from the itunes store in which case it's more around 360kbps. Unless you are using a dial up connection or downloading from a slow server, your download shouldn't be taking 10 hours.